# Selecting images and then moving them

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to figure out how to select an object first then I am able to move it. For example I want to select cow first by touching it then I am able to move it. The reason being is when I am touching the screen it is moving both cow  and cow1. When I only want to move one cow at a time. Any help will be appreciated.

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    cow.center = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);

    cow1.center = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);

}
```

Comment: There generally isn't a notion of "select an object first", but rather just add a gesture recognize on the view, that way as you start a gesture over the object in question, the drag will take place. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using UIPanGestureRecognizer, like this:

```
@synthesize myImage; //UIImageView

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startMoveImage];
}

-(void) startMoveImage{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

        CGPoint position = [gesture locationInView:[myImage superview]];
        [myImage setCenter:position];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement this sort of thing. It depends on how your graphics are implemented, amongst other things, check out this Apple sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution would be to add separate gesture recognizers for your two cow objects, e.g., in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panCow1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveCow:)];
[cow1 addGestureRecognizer:panCow1];
// if non ARC, make sure to add a line that says
// [panCow1 release];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panCow2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveCow:)];
[cow2 addGestureRecognizer:panCow2];
// if non ARC, make sure to add a line that says
// [panCow2 release];
```

And then you have your `moveCow` method look something like:

```
- (void)moveCow:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translate = [sender translationInView:self.view];

        sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translate.x, sender.view.center.y + translate.y);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but you get the idea. This is how I generally move separate subviews around...

Comment: By the way, the use of `translationInView` to adjust the center rather than `locationInView` for force the center means that you don't have some weird "jump" as you start the drag.